# How to filter pyspark dataframe with last 14 days?

Tags: pyspark, pyspark-pandas

I am having a date column in my dataframe

[image]

I wanted to filter out the last 14 days from the dataframe using the date column.
I tried the below code but it's not working

```
  last_14 = df.filter((df('Date')> date_add(current_timestamp(), -14)).select("Event_Time","User_ID","Impressions","Clicks","URL", "Date")
```

Event_time, user_id, impressions, clicks, URL is my other columns

Can anyone advise how to do this?

Comment: Could you elaborate how it is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

df  = spark.createDataFrame(
      [
    ('2022-03-10',),
    ('2022-03-09',),
    ('2022-03-08',),
    ('2022-02-02',),
    ('2022-02-01',)
      ], ['Date']
    ).withColumn('Date', F.to_date('Date', 'y-M-d'))

df\
    .filter((F.col('Date') > F.date_sub(F.current_date(), 14)))\
    .show()
```

```
+----------+
|      Date|
+----------+
|2022-03-10|
|2022-03-09|
|2022-03-08|
+----------+
```

In your code it would be:

```
 last_14 = df.filter((F.col('Date') > F.date_sub(F.current_date(), 14))).select("Event_Time","User_ID","Impressions","Clicks","URL", "Date")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another similar solution (it's just a matter of style preference) is to use [`expr`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.expr.html) to write a SQL expression:

```
last_14 = df.filter(F.col('Date') > F.expr(f'current_date() - interval 14 days'))

last_14.show()
+----------+
|      Date|
+----------+
|2023-07-10|
|2023-07-09|
|2023-07-08|
+----------+
```